# How to document nested classes with Sphinx's autodoc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, inner-classes, autodoc

Is there any way to document a nested class with Sphinx's autodoc plugin?

In:

```
class A:
    class B:
    """
    class B's documentation.
    """

    # ...
```

I want to use `autoclass` or something similar in my `.rst` file to document `A.B` specifically.

I tried:

```
.. currentmodule:: package.module

.. autoclass:: A.B
```

and

```
.. autoclass:: package.module.A.B
```

without success:

```
/path/to/file.rst:280: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'B' from module 'package.module.A'; the following exception was raised:

...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named 'package.module.A'; 'package.module' is not a package
```

Of course `A` is not a module; it seems like `autoclass` is considering anything before the last `.` as packages and modules.

Comment: This isn't an answer to how to get Sphinx to do what you want, but nested classes are very uncommon in Python, so you might continue to find poor support for them.  You could make your classes unnested and get Sphinx to work very easily.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately, those nested classes are part of an already existing API. The next major version should unnest them, but in the meantime, I still have to document them.

Comment: I created a Sphinx [bug report](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2820).

Comment: We use nested classes all the time, both to keep the global namespace as clean as possible and to convey context.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

`.. autoclass:: package.module::A.B`

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/IL5V7HR1ZYE

Comment: Still hasn't been fixed