# sphinx autodoc dynamic inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am new to using Sphinx and stumbled upon a problem while using the autodoc function (`sphinx-apidoc`).

One of my modules defines a function that uses dynamic inheritance, like this:

```
def generate_object(base_class, *args, **kwargs):
    """This function create a new class that inherits base_class
    """

    class NewClass(base_class):
        """Class that inerherits the base_class
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(NewClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            pass

    return NewClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

I then use the standard `sphinx-quickstart` in a `docs` folder and create the necessary `.rst` files using

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../
```

After running `make html` from the `docs` folder the generated site shows the documentation for the `generate_object` method but not for `NewClass`. How can I ensure that the documentation for `NewClass` is generated and shown in the documentation?

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/BartKeulen/smartstart/blob/master/smartstart/smartexploration/smartexploration.py), and the documentation [here](https://bartkeulen.github.io/smartstart/source/smartstart.smartexploration.html#module-smartstart.smartexploration.smartexploration)

Comment: `automodule` imports a module in order to document it. But I doubt that it can document a class (with or without dynamic inheritance) whose definition exists in the body of a function in the module.

Comment: Is there a recommended way around this?

Comment: Describing `NewClass` in the docstring of the `generate_object` function is what I can think of. Btw, here is a similar question about documenting classes defined within classes (I don't know if it helps though): https://stackoverflow.com/q/27337534/407651